# Accidentally formatted data. Please help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery

Last night I decided to dual boot my computer. I set up partitions and got everything set up how it should, It was roughly 3 am at the time I did this and I wasnt thinking clearly, but I said to delete the current operating system and install Ubuntu, Idgaf about windows, I could care less if I ever touch it again. I just want the files that I had on Windows back, I had some projects that I had been working on for months and they're gone now. I checked my drive partitions and There is 3, one huge one mounted on / and then 2 smaller ones that are around 3Gb, If there is ANY way to recover my old files, PLEASE tell me. I need these old files back.

Answer (score 0):

@Ex1Le

> Formatting doesn't mean that you have lost your data

1. First of All please don't use your PC until you recover your whole data because it will over write files on your previous precious data.
2. Okay Go to another pc download **Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD)**.
3. Make a **Bootable USB**.
   You can download **UBCD** from [This Link](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html)
   There are many ways to download from this official link i.e, Torrents,external mirror sites etc.

> UBCD has more than 100 tools for data recovery.
>   I hope it will help a lot....
>   I also had same problem once and I recovered my 238GB of data using the same.
>   Blockquote
>   
>   Please let me know if you don not have any experience with this method. I will do my best to resolve your problem Step-by-Step.

Comment: I have no experience with this method, I have the UBCD ISO on a bootable USB.

Comment: Okay if you have that **UBCD** file then what you have to do is to run on that formatted HDD hope it will resolve your Problem